# SQLAlchemy+PyMysql: how to recover from stale connection error (pymysql.err.InternalError)

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I clearly seem to be missing something: I would expect SQLAlchemy to recover from stale connections, by recreating them at 'checkout'.

My app is connecting and communicating to MYSQL database, using SQLAlchemy ORM (strictly ORM, not using expression language at all). When there is no activity for a period of time, the connections in the pool seem to go stale and generates

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1046, 'No database selected')
```

I have tried setting pre-ping also also have pool_recycle in create_engine.

I created a sample to test this: note that pool_recycle is aggressive to try produce the error situation faster (in my app, it is 3600)

```
# my test program in .py file
# - fully working code - BUT replace name/pwd/Dbserver in create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event, exc
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Integer, DateTime
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import pymysql

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://name:pwd@127.0.0.1',
                       pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=1)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS satest')
    # create and use the DB
    engine.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS satest')
    engine.execute('USE satest')

    # Prepare for creating tables
    metadata = MetaData(engine)
    # session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    base = declarative_base()


class TblFoo(base):
     __tablename__ = 'Foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    counter = Column(Integer)
    dateTime = Column(DateTime)


def createFooRecords():
    count = 1
    while count < 1000000:
        realCount = count
        try:
            global Session
            session = Session()
            rec = TblFoo(counter=count,
                         dateTime=datetime.today().isoformat())
            session.add(rec)
            session.commit()
            count += 1
        finally:
            session.close()

        if realCount != count:
            sleep(realCount*5)


@event.listens_for(engine, "handle_error")
def receive_handle_error(exception_context):
    print('Handle Error: ', exception_context)
    if isinstance(exception_context.original_exception, 
                  pymysql.err.InternalError):
        if str(exception_context.original_exception) == '1046':
            print('Internal Error: ')
        else:
            print('Some other error: ', 
                   exception_context.original_exception)


@event.listens_for(engine, 'invalidate')
def receive_invalidate(dbapi_connection, connection_record, exception):
    print('DBAPI connection: ', dbapi_connection)
    print('Conn Record: ', connection_record)
    print('Exception: ', exception)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    createFooRecords()
```

For sure, the connection in the engine.pool times out after 1 sec, and the second call to session.add(rec) fails.

"handle_error" does get called.

```
Handle Error:  <sqlalchemy.engine.base.ExceptionContextImpl object at 0x1093311d0>
Some other error:  (1046, 'No database selected')
Traceback (most recent call last):
.... stacktrace omitted for brevity, finally .... 
ssqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1046, 'No database selected') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO `Foo` (counter, `dateTime`) VALUES (%(counter)s, %(dateTime)s)'] [parameters: {'counter': 2, 'dateTime': '2019-08-28T15:07:45.184456'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

"invalidate" never gets called.

So why isn't SQLAlchemy not recreating the connection, knowing well that it would have expired in 1 sec (pool_recycle value). (Unclear if it is doing pre-ping either - how do I verify? -- but if it happening, it still is not recreating the connection.)

Admittedly, the error is coming from PyMysql but the settings are in SQLAlchemy.

Of course, I want to this recoverable, so I added a except to the try-catch: but perhaps recreating engine is not the right way to go about it.

```
def createFooRecords():
    count = 1
    while count < 1000000:
        realCount = count
        try:
            global Session
            session = Session()
            rec = TblFoo(counter=count, 
                         dateTime=datetime.today().isoformat())
            session.add(rec)
            session.commit()
            count += 1
        except exc.InternalError as e:
            print('{} Exception: {}'.format(count, e))
            global engine
            engine.dispose()
            engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://name:pwd@127.0.0.1',
                                   pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=1)
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            continue
        except Exception as e2:
            print('Error', e2)
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        if realCount != count:
            sleep(realCount*5)



Handle Error:  <sqlalchemy.engine.base.ExceptionContextImpl object at 0x1076b6fd0>
Some other error:  (1046, 'No database selected')
2 Exception: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1046, 'No database selected') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO `Foo` (counter, `dateTime`) VALUES (%(counter)s, %(dateTime)s)'] [parameters: {'counter': 2, 'dateTime': '2019-08-28T15:09:47.498157'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
2 Exception: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1046, 'No database selected') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO `Foo` (counter, `dateTime`) VALUES (%(counter)s, %(dateTime)s)'] [parameters: {'counter': 2, 'dateTime': '2019-08-28T15:09:47.503714'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

... and a countless stream of these as one would expect when 'count' is never incremented.

So net net, how  to recover from stale connections (preferably at checkout). I have a fairly complex application that uses only ORM, and has many many database (read: ORM Table) read-writes scattered thruout, so even other suggestions like lambda or a central function to run queries, etc is not very practical (or should it be?) Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you don't define the database name in your connection url. The documented pattern is `dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database` and you supply `'mysql+pymysql://name:pwd@127.0.0.1'`. So you have supplied dialect, driver, username, password and host, but no database.

In this block of code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS satest')
    # create and use the DB
    engine.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS satest')
    engine.execute('USE satest')

    # Prepare for creating tables
    metadata = MetaData(engine)
    # session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    base = declarative_base()
```

... you first drop the whole database every time you start your application, create it again, and manually issue the `USE satest` query. The thing is, that `USE satest` command only applies to a single connection that is checked out from the pool. It will stand for as long as the pool returns you that same connection, but as soon as a new connection is created, it hasn't had the `USE satest` command issued to it.

My advice is to create you database once and leave it there. Then, change your above code to this:

```py
...
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://name:pwd@127.0.0.1/satest')
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Prepare for creating tables
    metadata = MetaData(engine)
    # session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    base = declarative_base()
    base.metadata.drop_all()
    base.metadata.create_all()
```

If you really want to keep doing what you are doing, pymysql connections accept an [`init_command`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html#module-pymysql.connections) parameter which according to their docs is an:

> Initial SQL statement to run when connection is established.

So you can pass `"USE satest"` command through to that connection argument. You can read about how to do that [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments), but one example might be:

```py
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://name:pwd@127.0.0.1/satest', connect_args={"init_command": "USE satest"})
```

Comment: That's a great observation: we originally did have the DB in the create_engine URL so I have to go back and check why it was removed and the USE... added. (BTW, I am cleaning up the DB in the test env: in normal production use, there is not DROP / CREATE. But the USE is there, perhaps incorrectly so as you mention.) Will run some tests...

Comment: Well that sure does work quite well in the above test case, though it's only been a few minutes. No reason it won't in the actual app. I feel really stupid about this. But hey, that's the learning process, right.

Comment: No need to feel stupid, you asked a good question with enough information to easily identify the cause of your problem.

Comment: I actually had made this change in the app but not in the test program. I did "sense" that it worked "better than before" but with active debugging, did not register this is why. However, the change was made not as a way to fix this problem to to just be more specific in the URL and also based on some samples out there. Seemed the right thing to do. However, your answer has nailed it, and hopefully will help others down the line. Thanx again.